# Python Group by function

Tags: python, scatter-plot

and first of all, thanks to all the peeps here helping out others. I'm currently undergoing a career change and working on a Dataset with Coviddata as a training project.

The issue I am having is that I have daily reports on covid Data but since that, in the last two years, is a massive amount of data, I want to group the data into year_month so that all the data from each month of each year of data that I have gets combined for more accessible and better visualizations/scatterplots.

First, I changed the Datatype of the date column as it was displayed as an object.

```
dfgermany['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfgermany['date'])
```

#Scatterplot between total vaccinations and people fully vaccinated in Germany

```
plt.scatter(dfgermany['date'].tolist(), dfgermany['people_fully_vaccinated'])
plt.title('Date vs People fully Vaccinated')  
#plt.xlabel('Date from 2020-01 until 2022-04-19')  
plt.ylabel('People Fully Vaccinated')  
plt.show()
```

However, the result in the axis is visually not very pleasing as the Dates get overlapped.

So I am thinking of somehow grouping the data and displaying each month's summary.
After looking up this for quite some time, I worked on this.

```
dfgermany['year_month'] = dfgermany['date'].dt.to_period('M')
```

which created a new column called year_month [name to be edited]

following this, I used

```
dfgermany.groupby(['year_month']).sum()
```

which gave me the exact result I wanted, but I somehow did not get this to be "saved."

Dropping the date column is not an issue there.

```
dfgermany.drop(['date'], axis=1)
```

I am Leaving only the year_month column for each day's life datapoint.

After this, I changed the data type back to DateTime

```
dfgermany['year_month'] = dfgermany['year_month'].astype(str)

dfgermany['year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(dfgermany['year_month'])
```

This is the result I'm getting.

The problem I'm having now is that the axis labels are still not readable, and the data is instead stacked over each other than grouped. . When I use the group function, the result is changed but not saved so that I can use it for a scatterplot.

```
dfgermany.groupby(['year_month']).sum()
```

The output looks exactly like I want but is not saved for the scatterplot... I researched this the whole day and didn't get any further. Can someone here assist, or better enlighten me on where I made a mistake?

Sorry for the wall of text on my first post

UPDATE

My Basecode/Testset i used for all trials so far is this one

#importing libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
```

#This option ensures that the graphs you create are displayed within the notebook without the need to "call" them specifically.

```
%matplotlib inline
```

#creating path

```
path = r'C:\Users\stefa\Jupyter Analysis\14-04-2022 Achievement6'
```

#importing Dataframe

```
dfgermany = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, '02 Data', 'Prepared Data', 'CovidDE.csv'), index_col = False)
```

#Mathploblib known issue checkup with Version

```
matplotlib.__version__

enter code here
```

#Data Consistency checkup

```
dfgermany

dfgermany.dtypes

dfgermany['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfgermany['date'])



I am fairly new to all this so i'm truly sorry if i'm asking probably easy things . I didnt know how i can add the test dataset i have from Our World in Data https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus/country/germany
```

Comment: looks to me like what you want is something along the lines of ```df_toPlot = dfgermany.groupby(['year_month']).sum().to_frame()```  df_toPlot is now a new dataframe containing the grouped sums

Comment: df_toPlot = dfgermany.groupby(['year_month']).sum().to_frame()

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any sample input data nor any expected output data it is difficult to reproduce your problem, so forgive any of the following assumptions which maybe incorrect.

given a input dataframe of the form:

```
  Movie Day Length  View_Time
0   A   2   2.6     1.8
1   A   3   2.6     2.6
2   B   1   5.8     2.9
3   A   4   2.6     2.6
4   B   6   5.8     4.2
5   A   0   2.6     0.5
6   B   3   5.8     2.0

xdf = df.groupby(['Movie', 'Day']).Length.sum().to_frame()
```

will create a new dataframe

```
              Length
Movie   Day 
A        0    2.6
2             2.6
3             2.6
4             2.6
B        1    5.8
3             5.8
6             5.8
```

Since you seem to be wanting to create a new dataframe that you can plot, this should provide the result you are looking for.

If this isn't the answer you need, please provide sufficient data so we can reproduce your problem